# Android: Saving to SD Card always deletes on re-install

Tags: android, save, external, sd-card

I am using the getExternalFilesDir(null) method to save to the SD card. Saving and reading from the SD card is fine. The problem I am having is that every time I edit anything in Eclipse and rerun the app the data on the SD card is deleted. I know that saving to the directory returned by getExternalFilesDir(null) will allow the files there to be deleted when my app is uninstalled but is there a way to turn it off for just app updating? Is this only cause I am doing it from Eclipse and it won't delete the data when the app is updated from the market? Thanks for any info you can give me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is a bug in Android 2.2](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b68d40b1f13e12df/f3f37cc59d35617). Patches will become available over the next few months for 2.2 devices. You may wish to hold off using this feature until the next Android OS update.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So where on the SD card should I save files? Is there a standard to follow?

Comment: @Corey Alexander: there is no current standard, other than putting stuff in a directory (so you don't clutter up the SD card root).

Answer (score 2):

From what I read elsewhere the current *standard of the month* is a subdirectory in /sdcard/Android. i.E.:

```
final java.io.File Storage = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory ();
final java.io.File Dir = new java.io.File (Storrage, "Android/" + getPackageName ());
Dir.mkdirs ();
```

We can only hope that the bug is fixed very soon.

Comment: I think this where the file is saved getExternalFilesDir(null). So if I save to the place you recommend I think I would get the same bug just indirectly.

Comment: No, getExternalFilesDir(null) gives you: "Android/data/" + getPackageName ()

Note the "data" part. if you use that directory ("Android/data") then the files will be deleted even if you did not actually use getExternalFilesDir(null) to get/create the directory.

Trust me i tried it all.

Comment: On my phone, no application have something written under sdcard/Android. Does not seems to be any kind of a practice :) And maybe indeed it is not wise to put something under "Android" that is not actually managed by Android.

Answer (score 0):

if you do require the data, why don't you try renaming the package. In that case you may be left with multiple copies of the application but I think your data still remains intact.